# Socket not open correctly when using Threads c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winsock

Hey in trying to parctice with sockets and threading.
Im trying to do a little program that accept clients from one thread and add messages from client into queue. and from another thread print the messages to console.

but for some reason when i split the proccess to 2 threads, the socket not opened correctly and the listen function return 10022 error on WSAGetLastError.

the source code:

```
void SlaveThread(queue<char*>* tasks);
void MasterThread(queue<char*>* tasks);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    queue<char*>* tasksQueue = new queue<char*>();

    thread SecondThread(MasterThread,tasksQueue);
    thread FirstThread(SlaveThread,tasksQueue);

    FirstThread.join();
    SecondThread.join();
    return 0;
};


void SlaveThread(queue<char*>* tasks)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (!tasks->empty())
        {
            cout << tasks->front() << " Queue size : " << tasks->size() << endl;
            tasks->pop();
        }

        Sleep(1000);
    }
};

void MasterThread(queue<char*>* tasks)
{
    WSAData WinSockData;
    WORD Version = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

    WSAStartup(Version, &WinSockData);

    /* Create socket structure */
    SOCKADDR_IN Server;
    Server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.7");
    Server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Server.sin_port = htons(27015);

    SOCKET ListenSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    SOCKET Connect;
    bind(ListenSock, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, sizeof(Server));
    listen(ListenSock, 1);
    int errno1 = WSAGetLastError();
    cout << "Listening on port 27015" << endl;
    //char buffer[200];
    int size = sizeof(Server);
    while (true)
    {
        if (Connect = accept(ListenSock, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, &size)){
            int errno1 = WSAGetLastError();
            cout << "Connection established.. " << endl;
        }
        //if (recv(ListenSock, buffer, 200, 0) > 0)
        //{
        //  tasks->push(buffer);
        //}
    }

    WSACleanup();
};
```

any suggestion why it's break when i add threads to program? because on empty program just opening the socket with the same code it's work properly.

Comment: how do you know `ListenSock` is valid? You aren't checking the return code from `socket`.

Comment: i checked now the value of ListenSock and it's not equal to INVALID_SOCKET then i guess it's valid @SamMiller

Comment: 10022, FWIW, is WSAEINVAL for invalid argument.

Comment: @Santa i know what this error mean but in every example of opening socket this is the values they send to listen so the arguments should be fine. BTW after socket() and bind() the WSAGetLastError() return 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use INADDR_ANY
2) Use ::bind instead of bind.  The name is ambiguous to an standard template library call.  This is why using namespace std is bad.

```
void MasterThread(queue<char*>* tasks)
{
    WSAData WinSockData;
    WORD Version = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

    WSAStartup(Version, &WinSockData);

    /* Create socket structure */
    SOCKADDR_IN Server;
    Server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;//inet_addr("10.0.0.7");
    Server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Server.sin_port = htons(27015);

    SOCKET ListenSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
    SOCKET Connect;
    ::bind(ListenSock, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, sizeof(Server));
    int errno0 = WSAGetLastError();
    listen(ListenSock, 1);
    int errno1 = WSAGetLastError();
    cout << "Listening on port 27015" << endl;
    //char buffer[200];
    int size = sizeof(Server);
    while (true)
    {
        if (Connect = accept(ListenSock, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, &size)){
            int errno1 = WSAGetLastError();
            cout << "Connection established.. " << endl;
        }
        //if (recv(ListenSock, buffer, 200, 0) > 0)
        //{
        //  tasks->push(buffer);
        //}
    }

    WSACleanup();
};
```

Comment: I don't think `using namespace std` would be a problem here. I doubt it'd mix up `bind` with `std::bind`. Maybe overload resolution would kick in or some other magic..

Comment: Thank you! ::bind solved it, probably there was an ambigiuos like you said!

Comment: You are welcome.  It was awful luck that the std::bind actually compiled and ran!  You should check the return values from all those socket functions.  Had you done so initially, you would have noticed that bind() wasn't returning an integer like it is supposed to.